# Structuremap won't initialise when ASP.net site is published

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, structuremap

I have a .Net 4.0 webforms web app which I use StructureMap for DI. When I debug the site in VS 2013, it works fine, but when I publish the site, it doesn't appear to initialise the ObjectFactory correctly and I get the following error when executing a method on a page.:

> StructureMap.StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code: 202
>   No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily
>   ServerConfiguration.DataCollection.IOnlineStateCollector,
>   ServerConfiguration.DataCollection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null at StructureMap.BuildSession.<.ctor>b__0(Type t)
>   at StructureMap.Util.Cache`2.get_Item(KEY key) at
>   StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) at
>   StructureMap.Container.GetInstanceT at
>   ServerConfiguration.Web.WebForms.CollectData.GetOnlineStateData(String
>   serverName) at
>   ServerConfiguration.Web.WebForms.CollectData.SubmitButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

I am calling a `BootstrapStructureMap()` method from `Application_Start` in global.asax file which calls the `ObjectFactory.Initialize()` method for StructureMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue. It was due to selecting Precompile as part of the publishing options. When I turned it off, it worked ok.